# Compare two columns in pandas. How to check which row is different?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare two columns in pandas. These two columns are all string. What commands can give the results showing which row is different between these two rows. Please find detailed codes below.

```
dfk['County Name_x'].equals(dfk['County Name_y'])
```

`Out[198]: False`

However, I cannot see which row is different.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
dfk['County Name_x'].eq(dfk['County Name_y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the equality operator between the two columns will give a series of bools. The rows where the value is false correspond to the rows in the column that are not equal. Try `df['column1']==df['column2']`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

`dfk.loc[dfk['County Name_x'] != dfk['County Name_y']]`